# Error : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') in frontend

Tags: ether, wagmi, wagmi-hooks, viem

```
import contracts from '../RPSLS.sol/RPSLSFinal.json'
import { ChangeEvent, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useLocalStorage } from '../hooks/useLocalStorage.ts'
import { useAccount, useContractWrite, useSignMessage } from 'wagmi';
import { Address, Hash, encodePacked, keccak256, parseEther } from 'viem';
import { AppContext } from '../Acontext/Appcontext.tsx';
import { Move, movesIcons, moves } from '../moves'
import { Home } from './Home'

export const NewGame = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [player2, setPlayer2] = useState('')
    const [bid, setBid] = useState('')
    const [, setSalt] = useLocalStorage('salt');
    const [, setMove1] = useLocalStorage('move');
    const [selectedMove, setSelectedMove] = useState(Move.Null)
    const [isMoveCommitted, setIsMoveCommitted] = useState(false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const account = location.state?.account;
    const {
        error,
        isLoading: isNewGameSessionLoading,
        write: createNewGameSession,
        data: createNewGameSessionData,
      } = useContractWrite({
        ...contracts.factory,
        functionName: 'createGameSession',
        value: parseEther(bid),
      });

    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const _salt = useRef();

    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const _move1Hash = useRef();

    const { signMessage, data: signData } = useSignMessage();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (createNewGameSessionData && createNewGameSessionData.hash && !error) {
            setIsMoveCommitted(true);
        }
    }, [createNewGameSessionData && createNewGameSessionData.hash, error]);

    const [gameSessionHash, setGameSessionHash] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!createNewGameSessionData && signData && _move1Hash.current && player2) {
            createNewGameSession({
                args: [_move1Hash.current, player2],
            });
        }
    }, [createNewGameSessionData, signData, _move1Hash.current, player2]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (gameSessionHash && _salt.current) {
            setSalt(_salt.current, `salt-${gameSessionHash}`);
            setMove1(String(selectedMove), `move-${gameSessionHash}`);
        }
    }, [gameSessionHash, selectedMove]);

    const { setErrorMessage, setIsLoading } = useContext(AppContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (error && error.message) {
            setErrorMessage && setErrorMessage(error.message);
        }
    }, [error && error.message]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading && setIsLoading(isNewGameSessionLoading);
    }, [isNewGameSessionLoading]);


    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    const handleMoveSelection = (move) => {
        setSelectedMove(move);
    };

    const handleClick = () => {
        const salt = crypto.randomUUID();

        _move1Hash.current = keccak256(
          encodePacked(['uint8', 'string'], [selectedMove, salt]),
        );

        _salt.current = salt;

        signMessage({
          message: `Your game move is: ${selectedMove}. Your game salt is: ${_salt.current}. Keep it private! It'll automatically be stored in your local storage.`,
        });
        navigate('/gamesession')
    }

    return (
        <>
            <p className='account' style={{ color: 'black' }}> Account : {account ? account : "Not connected"}</p>
            <div>
                <h2>Player 1 Selection</h2>
                <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    {moves.map((move, index) => (
                        <div key={move} style={{ backgroundColor: selectedMove === move ? "#333" : "#fff", padding: "10px" }}>
                            <img
                                src={movesIcons[index]}
                                alt={move}
                                style={{ cursor: 'pointer', height: "250px", width: "250px" }}
                                onClick={() => handleMoveSelection(move)}
                            />
                            <p style={{ color: selectedMove === move ? "#fff" : "#000" }}>{move}</p>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <p>Selected Move: {selectedMove}</p>
            </div>
            <form className='details' onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
                <div className='player2Adrs'>
                    <label for="name">Player 2's Address:</label>
                    <input value={player2} type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={(e) => setPlayer2(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter your address"></input>
                </div>
                <div className='bid'>
                    <label>Please enter the bid for the game:</label>
                    <input value={bid} type='number' id='bid' name='bidforgame' onChange={(e) => setBid(e.target.value)} placeholder='bid for the game'></input>
                </div>
                <button type='submit' onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? What were you doing? What contracts are you using? Usually, that error means something wasn't initialized correctly, or something else caused an error. Try to find where the null is being assigned and backtrack from there.